# Compile time if else in c++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have this template function -

```
template <int N> 
void foo() {
  if (N < 2) {
    bar1();
  } else {
    bar2();
  }
}
```

I want to deduce if else during compile time in C++11 to make the function efficient. I thought of adding an additional template bool variable like this -

```
template <int N, bool I = (N < 2), std::enable_if<I>> 
void foo() {
    bar1();
}
template <int N, bool I = (N < 2), std::enable_if<!I>> 
void foo() {
    bar2();
}
```

Not sure if this is the right approach. Can anyone please help?

Comment: No C++17 access?

Comment: This is a small part of big code compiled in C++11. Can't switch as of now

Comment: The instantiations of the original function template will make it really easy for the compiler to optimize the "dead" branch away completely. `foo<2>();` would make it `if(2 < 2)` in `foo<2>` and with optimization turned on I bet _all_ compilers would remove that branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++11, you can use `enable_if` to write 2 overloads

```
template <int N, typename std::enable_if<N < 2, int*>::type = nullptr> 
void foo() {
    bar1();
}

template <int N, typename std::enable_if<N >= 2, int*>::type = nullptr> 
void foo() {
    bar2();
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zqPa5Mhx5)

Note that this is unlikely to give you any performance advantage. Compilers will be able to use the template parameter `N` in the `if` condition to remove the unneeded branch.